# How to change the advanced setting from registry

Tags: c++, mfc

Hi i am trying to change the elements in advanced setting from registry. I am able to change the values, but there is not change in User Interface i.e,(Font Smoothing). what i need to do after changing the values in registry??

Comment: Probably reboot the computer.  Unless documented there is no guarantee that registry changes will have an immediate effect.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your suggestion. Yes, this one way to do it. But if u do the changes in advanced settings and click apply it just refreshes your system(I guess u noticed it), it means that internally they are invoking some api to refresh it..

Comment: What registry exactly are you changing ?

Comment: The registry is usually not an official programming interface (it certainly isn't in this case). Use the official API ([SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx)) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what settings you are modifying.

But most system settings like those changed with [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) imply the use of [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) .

So in fact: Changing the registry directly might be the wrong way.

Comment: Thank you, I ll try with this.

Comment: Yes, you are write.. now i am able to do it without changing the registry values...